# Are all resistors parallel in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am trying to figure out the total resistance for this circuit.

Are all resistors in parallel?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The five resistors are independant - neither series or parallel.

As there are integrated circuits in the circuit, it does not make sense to determine a "total resistance" of the circuit.  The current drawn by the circuit will vary, depending on what the ICs are doing.